# Duality between acceptance region of testing and confidence region in terms of optimality?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, confidence-interval

The duality theorem between acceptance region of testing and confidence region is  about their validity (i.e. satisfying the significance level of the former and the confidence level of the latter sum up to be 1). For example, this is what is given in Casella's Statistical Inference.

I was wondering if there is  some duality result about their optimality? By "optimality":

- for confidence interval, it can mean the length of the interval is minimum, or something else;
- for acceptance region of testing, it can mean the power of the testing has uniformly maximum power, or the length of the acceptance region is minimum.

Thanks and regards!

Comment: Nice question! I think there's something in chapter/section 5.5.2 of The Bayesian Choice. The author states that the answer is negative. Translating an optimal test into CI, may not give an optimal CI.